# Is it possible to change a roku device’s OS to windows?

Tags: windows, operating-system, roku

Basically, I want to turn my roku device into a computer I guess. I haven’t tried anything yet. I just wanted to see if it’s even possible. I’m getting a server and I want to run everything from that server to the windows roku to a tv screen.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to change a Roku's operating system.